# Infected square

Tags: co.combinatorics

I saw the following problem in Mathematical Puzzles from Peter Winkler (very good book, by the way): imagine you infect k cases of a chessboard nxn and the infection spreads to a case if it has at least two neighbors infected. Then k = n is the minimum number such that it is possible to infect the whole chessboard.
I would like to know if it is known what happen in higher dimensions and other values for the number of neighbors for a case to be infected?

Comment: The magic words are bootstrap percolation.

Comment: bootstrap percolation consider a initial probability for each case to be infected, isn't it? Here is the goal is not to find the threshold but the exact number.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas so *that* is what "squeamish ossifrage" actually meant?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Good comment for the well-informed (or those with access to google like me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an d-dimensional version of this problem in *The Art of Mathematics - Coffee Time in Memphis* by Bela Bollobas. (Problem 35)

According to it, the answer is $k = \lceil d(n-1)/2 \rceil + 1$.